# How to block SSL protocols in favor of TLS?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cherrypy, pyopenssl

How can I block SSL protocols in `PyOpenSSL` in favour of `TLS`? I'm using `CentOS 7` and have these versions:

```
pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-3.el7.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.7.x86_64
```

In my config file (this if for a CherryPy app) I have:

```
'server.ssl_module': 'pyopenssl',
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really good question for CherryPy today. This month we started discussing SSL issues and overall maintainability of CherryPy's wrappers over py2.6+ `ssl` and pyOpenSSL in [CherryPy user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cherrypy-users). I'm planning a topic about SSL issues there, so you can subscribe for the group to get more details later.

For now, here's what is possible. I had Debian Wheezy, Python 2.7.3-4+deb7u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-2+deb7u16. I've installed CherryPy from the repo (3.6 has broken SSL), and pyOpenSSL 0.14. I tried to override both CherryPy SSL adapters to gain some points in Qualys SSL labs [test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest). It is very helpful and I strongly suggest you to test your deployment with it (whatever is your frontend, CherryPy or not).

As a result, `ssl`-based adapter still has vulnerabilities which I don't see the way to workaround in py2 < 2.7.9 (massive SSL update) and py3 < 3.3. Because CherryPy `ssl` adapter was written long before these changes, it needs a rewrite to support both old and new ways (mostly [SSL Contexts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts)). On the other hand with subclassed pyOpenSSL adapted it's mostly fine, except for:

- Enabled [Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/10/31/tls-renegotiation-and-denial-of-service-attacks). It may be OpenSSL-dependent.
- no [Forward Secrecy](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/06/25/ssl-labs-deploying-forward-secrecy), `SSL.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE` could have helped but it didn't. May also depend on version of OpenSSL.

Here's the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import sys
import ssl

import cherrypy
from cherrypy.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
from cherrypy.wsgiserver.ssl_pyopenssl import pyOpenSSLAdapter

from cherrypy import wsgiserver
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
  from cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2 import ssl_adapters  
else:
  from cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3 import ssl_adapters

try:
  from OpenSSL import SSL
except ImportError:
  pass


ciphers = (
  'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
  'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
  '!eNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!RC4:!SSLv2'
)

bundle = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cherrypy.__file__), 'test', 'test.pem')

config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8443,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8,

    'server.ssl_module'      : 'custom-pyopenssl',
    'server.ssl_certificate' : bundle,
    'server.ssl_private_key' : bundle,
  }
}


class BuiltinSsl(BuiltinSSLAdapter):
  '''Vulnerable, on py2 < 2.7.9, py3 < 3.3:
    * POODLE (SSLv3), adding ``!SSLv3`` to cipher list makes it very incompatible
    * can't disable TLS compression (CRIME)
    * supports Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation (DOS)
    * no Forward Secrecy
  Also session caching doesn't work. Some tweaks are posslbe, but don't really 
  change much. For example, it's possible to use ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1 instead of 
  ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 with little worse compatiblity.
  '''

  def wrap(self, sock):
    """Wrap and return the given socket, plus WSGI environ entries."""
    try:
      s = ssl.wrap_socket(
        sock, 
        ciphers = ciphers, # the override is for this line
        do_handshake_on_connect = True,
        server_side = True, 
        certfile = self.certificate,
        keyfile = self.private_key,
        ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23
      )
    except ssl.SSLError:
      e = sys.exc_info()[1]
      if e.errno == ssl.SSL_ERROR_EOF:
        # This is almost certainly due to the cherrypy engine
        # 'pinging' the socket to assert it's connectable;
        # the 'ping' isn't SSL.
        return None, {}
      elif e.errno == ssl.SSL_ERROR_SSL:
        if e.args[1].endswith('http request'):
          # The client is speaking HTTP to an HTTPS server.
          raise wsgiserver.NoSSLError
        elif e.args[1].endswith('unknown protocol'):
          # The client is speaking some non-HTTP protocol.
          # Drop the conn.
          return None, {}
      raise

    return s, self.get_environ(s)

ssl_adapters['custom-ssl'] = BuiltinSsl


class Pyopenssl(pyOpenSSLAdapter):
  '''Mostly fine, except:
    * Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation
    * no Forward Secrecy, SSL.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE could have helped but it didn't
  '''

  def get_context(self):
    """Return an SSL.Context from self attributes."""
    c = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)

    # override:
    c.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_COMPRESSION | SSL.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE | SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL.OP_NO_SSLv3)
    c.set_cipher_list(ciphers)

    c.use_privatekey_file(self.private_key)
    if self.certificate_chain:
        c.load_verify_locations(self.certificate_chain)
    c.use_certificate_file(self.certificate)
    return c

ssl_adapters['custom-pyopenssl'] = Pyopenssl


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '<em>Is this secure?</em>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

### Update

Here's [the article](http://recollection.saaj.me/article/cherrypy-questions-testing-ssl-and-docker.html#ssl) and [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cherrypy-users/ghrUwoyYKgI) where future of CherryPy's SSL support should be decided.

Comment: UPD: there's no separation between wsgiserver2 and wsgiserver3 nowadays

Comment: thank you for this -- i used this example code to configure how the python ftpserver module pyftpdlib uses openssl in order to limit the number of undesirable SSL ciphers it supports. for anyone interested, i used the awesome testssl.sh script to test it afterwards (https://testssl.sh/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it I am aware. One is a configuratio options, and the other is a runtime option.

***Configuration Option***

The configuration option is used when building OpenSSL. Its great for *all* applications because it applies your administrative policy and addresses applications which are not mindful to SSL/TLS related issues.

For this option, simply configure OpenSSL with `no-ssl2 no-ssl3`. `no-comp` is also often used because compression can leak information.

```
./Configure no-ssl2 no-ssl3 <other opts>
```

Other OpenSSL options are available, and you might want to visit [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on OpenSSL's wiki.

***Runtime Option***

In C, you have to (1) use the 2/3 method to get SSL 2/3 and above; and then (2) call `SSL_CTX_set_options` (or `SSL_set_options`) and (3) remove the SSL protocols. That leaves the TLS protocols:

```
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());
const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

In Python, you do it with `OpenSSL.SSL.Context.set_options`.

Comment: The leading `_` on the `_util` module means it's private.  It's not for application developers, it's internal to pyOpenSSL.  The correct API is `OpenSSL.SSL.Context.set_options`

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul Calderone; fixed.