# How to configure SparkPost SMTP in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, smtp, sparkpost

I was successfully using Mandrill to send mail from my CodeIgniter site, with this config :

```
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

But Mandrill doesn't want to do transactionnal email, so I need to migrate to SparkPost.
Here are their directives : https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1988470-smtp-connection-problems

I tried this config :

```
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.sparkpostmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

But no mail where send, with no error. So I tried to add "tls" in the host :

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://smtp.sparkpostmail.com';
```

And I get this error :

> Message:  fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
>   Filename: libraries/Email.php
>   Line Number: 1950

I got the same error on port 2525.

Here is my openssl section in phpinfo  on my local MAMP server :

> OpenSSL support   enabled
>   OpenSSL Library Version   OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14
>   July 2015 OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

But I have the same error on my Debian server, with phpinfo :

> OpenSSL support   enabled
>   OpenSSL Library Version   OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
>   OpenSSL Header Version    OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
>   Openssl default config    /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would say you need version 1.2 or even v3. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627991/1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number-call-on-indy) q/a.

Answer (score 6):

I was close:

SparkPost needs TLS and not SSL. It has to be setted in the parameters, and not in the server url, so that it use `STARTTLS`. And, last thing, I needed to change the default newline value. So here is the good config:

```
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.sparkpostmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$condig['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Comment: Sorry, was this an invoice app? I have the exact same issue when migrating from mandrill to sparkpost. The above fix is basically what I already have, and it's still not working here ... Any other tricks?

Comment: This worked for me: `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");`. For some reason, the config values for setting that weren't applying.

Comment: Thanks! spent hours trying to debug this, and your solution worked.