# Python 3.2 Cherrypy 3.2.3 ssl_module Error with pyopenssl

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy, raspbian, python-3.2

I'm running a webserver using **SSL** protocole from a **Raspberry Pi** and a **signed certificate** from Gandi.

The serwer worked with the **ssl_module = 'builtin'** in the config.
But as the browsers have issues with recognizing the certificate issuer, I need to give the intermediate certificate throught the **ssl_certificate_chain** attribute which can be only allowed by using the **ssl_module = 'pyopenssl'**. But this config doesn't work. (See error message)

```
ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0xe435b0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 205, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 167, in start
    self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 158, in httpserver_from_self
    httpserver = _cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpwsgi_server.py", line 60, in __init__
    adapter_class = wsgiserver.get_ssl_adapter_class(ssl_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver3.py", line 1882, in get_ssl_adapter_class
    adapter = ssl_adapters[name.lower()]
KeyError: 'pyopenssl'

[31/Jul/2015:16:04:18] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 243, in start
    self.publish('start')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 223, in publish
    raise exc
cherrypy.process.wspbus.ChannelFailures: KeyError('pyopenssl',)
```

**pyOpenSSL** is installed.
But when I do the test:

> '>>>import ssl
>
> '>>>import socket
>
> '>>>hasattr(socket, 'ssl')
>
> False

I also tried to rebuild **Python3.2** after installing **libssl-dev** with **pip-3.2**. But I didn't succeed and had to restore the whole system back.

thank you for any help!

Comment: Actually, I have many errors during pyopenssl install :

Answer (score 0):

At least for several CherryPy releases `ssl_builtin` [supports `certificate_chain`](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/6c5250a7703b385b2dc13429ba6a17202aeaa882/cherrypy/wsgiserver/ssl_builtin.py?at=default#ssl_builtin.py-42). Install CherryPy 3.7+ from the Cheese Shop (i.e. `pip install CherryPy`), not from Debian Pacakges. Python 3.2 itself is a good candidate for update (e.g. many libraries are 3.3+).

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29304038/2072035) to be aware of current CherryPy SSL issues. Or [this section](http://recollection.saaj.me/article/cherrypy-questions-testing-ssl-and-docker.html#python-3-support-for-pyopenssl-adapter) directly, as CherryPy doesn't currently support PyOpenSSL for Python 3.