# How to disable SSL3 and weak ciphers with cherrypy builtin ssl module (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, cherrypy

I have configured Cherrypy 3.8.0 with Python 3 to use SSL/TLS. However, I want to disable SSL3 to avoid POODLE. I searched through the documentation but I am unsure on how to implement it.

I am using the cherrypy/python builtin `ssl` module, not `pyOpenSSL` which I am unable to use under Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

To disable SSL3, you should set the `ssl_context` variable yourself rather than accepting the default. Here's an example using Python's built-in `ssl` module (in lieu of the built-in `cherrypy` ssl module).

```
import cherrypy
import ssl

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3

cherrypy.config.update(server_config)
```

where in this case, `SSL` is from the `OpenSSL` module.

It's worth noting that beginning in Python 3.2.3, the `ssl` module disables certain weak ciphers by default.

Furthermore, you can specifically set all the ciphers you want with

```
ciphers = {
    'DHE-RSA-AE256-SHA',
    ...
    'RC4-SHA'
}

ctx.set_ciphers(':'.join(ciphers))
```

If you're using the `CherryPyWSGIServer` from the `web.wsgiserver` module, you would set the default ciphers with

```
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context.set_cipher_list(':'.join(ciphers))
```

Here is part of the documentation detailing the above: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.wsgiserver.html#module-cherrypy.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin

Lastly, here are some sources (asking similar questions) that you may want to look at:

- [How to block SSL protocols in favor of TLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260947/how-to-block-ssl-protocols-in-favor-of-tls)
- https://review.cloudera.org/r/4739/diff/
- http://roadha.us/2014/10/disable-sslv3-avoid-poodle-attack-web-py/
- http://blog.gosquadron.com/use-tls
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28073251/Disable-weak-SSL-cipher-on-CherryPy-pyOpenSSL-Windows-2008-Server.html

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately I need to use Python’s builtin `ssl` module, with CherryPy, not `pyopenssl` - which provides `OpenSSL` module. I tried your solution but checking with `openssl s_client ... -ssl3` it connects with ssl3, which I need to ensure to be disabled.

Comment: @fbrundu -- My mistake, I saw you say Python3 but I gave you the Python2 answer anyway! I've edited the answer above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work. Running with `openssl s_client ... -ssl3` it always gives me `Protocol  : SSLv3` .. Could it be that `ssl_context` works only with `pyOpenSSL` which does not work with cherrypy on Python3 ?

Comment: I have implemented a "proxy" in python2 just to test your solution. Now it cannot connect: it gives me `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas - Any chance you could repost your python 2 solution over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832932/disable-weak-ciphers-with-cherrypy-python-2. Thanks!

Comment: @jrel -- Just did. Glad I could help with that one, but this one is still confusing me. I'm going to edit as I found something that should work.

Comment: @fbrundu -- I edited the above to include http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.wsgiserver.html#module-cherrypy.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin for your Python 3 ssl issue. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas Unfortunately, it does not work. If I ask for SSLv3 it runs on SSLv3. If you need more information please ask. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MichaelRecachinas, I am giving you the bounty for the effort and because I think your answer may work but it does not due to Cherrypy. But I cannot accept the answer until it does not work, sorry.