# Disable weak ciphers with cherrypy (python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, cherrypy

I'm using Cherrypy 3.8.0 with Python 2 to use SSL/TLS using pyOpenSSL.

I want to disable SSL3 to avoid POODLE (or other weak ciphers).

Here's what I have so far:

```
  server_config={
          'server.socket_port': 443,
          'server.ssl_module':'pyopenssl',
          'server.ssl_certificate':'/path/myserver.crt',
          'server.ssl_private_key':'/path/myserver.key',
      }
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740951/how-to-disable-ssl3-and-weak-ciphers-with-cherrypy-builtin-ssl-module-python-3) but for python 2 and pyopenssl.

How can I specify or exclude specific ciphers? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To disable SSL3, you should set the `ssl_context` variable yourself rather than accepting the default. Here's an example using Python's built-in `ssl` module (in lieu of the built-in `cherrypy` ssl module).

```
import cherrypy
from OpenSSL import SSL

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL.OP_NO_SSLv3)

...

server_config = {
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': 443,
    'server.ssl_context': ctx
}

cherrypy.config.update(server_config)
```

where in this case, `SSL` is from the `OpenSSL` module.

It's worth noting that beginning in Python 3.2.3, the `ssl` module disables certain weak ciphers by default.

Furthermore, you can specifically set all the ciphers you want with

```
ciphers = {
    'DHE-RSA-AE256-SHA',
    ...
    'RC4-SHA'
}

ctx.set_cipher_list(':'.join(ciphers))
```

If you're using the `CherryPyWSGIServer` from the `web.wsgiserver` module, you would set the default ciphers with

```
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context.set_cipher_list(':'.join(ciphers))
```

Lastly, here are some sources (asking similar questions) that you may want to look at:

- [How to block SSL protocols in favor of TLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260947/how-to-block-ssl-protocols-in-favor-of-tls)
- https://review.cloudera.org/r/4739/diff/
- http://roadha.us/2014/10/disable-sslv3-avoid-poodle-attack-web-py/
- http://blog.gosquadron.com/use-tls
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28073251/Disable-weak-SSL-cipher-on-CherryPy-pyOpenSSL-Windows-2008-Server.html

Comment: Thanks Michael. But I'm getting an error that says: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'. A little searching shows I need python 2.7.9 for this, but my distro is fixed at 2.7.6 for now. :/ So I'm still in need of a 2.7.6 answer if possible.

Comment: Ah sorry, you may not have gotten my update -- error in porting it from the other question: `ctx = SSL.SSLContext` -> `ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not working for me. Specifically, I'm getting a browser error that says 'ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap'

Comment: Which browser are you using? You might find this link (from my answer) useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29304038/4760801

Comment: I'm testing with the latest firefox. Interesting link though. Sounds like it may be best to upgrade to 2.7.9 and get the SSL upgrades, unless I want to override pyopenssl.